# Why are Apple App Store price changes not propagating to sandbox/dev environment?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, storekit

Two changes made on App Store Connect (both Approved by Apple): (1) new subscription added. (2) a change to the description of an existing subscription.

The description change is reflected in the production/released app.

I do not expect to see the newly added subscription visible in the released app as a new release of the app has not been made.

The problem is: In my development build in Xcode, neither of the changes are visible. Instead, the previous subscriptions are still visible.

It looks like the changes have propagated to production but not to the development environment.

This is using StoreKit 2, iOS 16.1. But also tested on an iOS 17 device.

Here is what I have tried and/or checked:

- Both price/sub changes are Approved,
- Product codes are correct.
- Tried on a both simulator and real device.
- Deleted and re-installed dev app.
- No errors from Product.products(for:).
- Region is correct.
- Waited over a week for propagation to the sandbox/development environment.
- Paid apps agreement is current
- Deleted app and re-installed
- Cleared DerivedData directory on Mac
- Catalyst app tested on both iOS and Mac.
- Posted on Apple forums (no luck)
- Posted an Apple feedback ticket (FB12654744)

// The actual line of code. No runtime errors triggered.
// I have checked that the valid product ID is part of the keys array.

let storeProducts = try await Product.products(for: Array(productIDs.keys))

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

In my development debug Scheme, I had a leftover StoreKit Configuration in the Scheme Options. The fix was to set StoreKit Configuration to "None". The latent StoreKit config was masking the App Store Connect products.

Xcode > Product > Edit Scheme > Run/Debug > Options
StoreKit Configuration = None

Alternatively, sync the StoreKit Configuration with App Connect:

Xcode > Open your store kit config file > Tap Sync icon at bottom left where is says "Synced".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).